# Keras GPU usage

Tags: keras, gpu, tensorflow

I am using keras wrapper with tensorflow as backend. I have a huge image which I subtile into smaller images and run a script which generates a heatmap individually on them. As its using tensorflow as backend it uses GPU and optimizes the computation for that particular heat map. 
However I am trying to run multiple instances of the script at the same time on a single GPU using CUDA.

How do I calculate the % of GPU usage each time the script runs? I am planning to use the remaining part of GPU to parallelize the process.

Comment: Unless you are running the NVIDIA MPS service on your host (and I guess you are not), then what you are asking about isn't possible. Multiple host processes cannot simultaneously use a single CUDA GPU

Comment: if I have MPS service running, how do I go about checking the usage of my GPU for running a single instance of my program?